# git restore deleted files from uncommited changes in local

Tags: git

I have uncommitted changes in my local branch (development2) 
and there were some file that were inadvertently deleted.
I was restoring the files back into my local with the following command:

```
git checkout -- /path/to/my/files
```

I was copying and pasting each individual file using this command, unfortunately I ran the command

```
git checkout --
```

which brought back all the files, which I did not want to do, I wanted to go through and bring back specific files. 
I still have not committed my changes, is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have done `git add FILE_YOU_WANT` at lease once, `git reflog` might help you.

If no, no hope...